# Converting many faces to single mesh and reduce poly-count in Blender

Tags: models, blender, 3d-meshes

I'm not so familiar with 3D modelling, and I'm stuck on a simple task in Blender.

I have a fairly complex model that's been imported as a .DAE file from SketchUp. This model is composed of many polygons, not as one single mesh but in many components, in fact over many hundreds of surfaces.

As I said I'm new to Blender and want to learn. If I select one of the component surfaces, I can go into Edit mode and then use the Decimate modifier to reduce the poly-count.

But it doesn't want to let me do this if I select the whole object!

I think I need to combine all the surfaces into one mesh (?) and then apply the Decimate algorithm to gracefully reduce the poly-count.

I've managed to do this before but unfortunately I forgot how and I need to try again to get the balance right on the poly-count.

Appreciate the help.

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. select 2 or more  "components" (in Blender terms, these are separate objects) ([B] will box-select, may be easier than shift-clicking through all the objects)
2. [Ctrl] [J] "Join"

I haven't used Blender in a long time. What helped me learn some commands was remembering the name of the command. If you bring up the spacebar menu and type in "Join", it will bring back a list of all the commands containing that word, including their keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by just selecting the biggest objects and decimating them one at a time, rather than trying to do the whole object, although you'd think that would be possible.

I tried all the vertex/edge/face merging tools and none of them seemed to do anything, still need to figure that one.